# override ps1 script module function only working when launching script as admin

Tags: powershell

I'm currently working on a custom project using ps1 scripts and to achieve this the cleanest way possible I tried to use inheritance and override concepts.

For inheritance I used module functionality, thus I have a module.psm1 file providing mother's functions to children, everything working like a charm and making powershell script enough convenient for me.

About overriding concept, I am able to use a kind of overriding mechanism (not sure if override is the proper naming in this case, sorry if not) but it only works when my script is launched in Admin mode.

I guess my issue and question could be a bit tough, but I'll make it the clearest possible, let me know if you need further explanations.

I have a function A in module.psm1 which I can use in child.ps1 cause I properly made it usable using "Export-ModuleMember -Function A"
Inside this function A I use a function B which is not declared in module.psm1 but instead is declared in child.ps1. It's because A as a general behaviour which benefits several `childs.ps1` but B needs to be child specific.

The main purpose is to have a clean, factorized code, allowing easy maintaining

When I don't launch in Admin mode it doesn't work, i.e it says "function B not find" while in admin mode everything is fine, plus there is no need to launch as admin in this particular context I'm talking about.

```
#module.psm1 #AKA mother

function A ($optionalParam=$null){B}

Export-ModuleMember -Function A
```

WORKING WAY

```
#child.ps1
Import-Module "Module\module.psm1"


if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`" `"$args`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

function B ($optionalParam=$null){#somecode}
```

And it works great... in Admin mode only.

NOT WORKING

```
#child.ps1
Import-Module "Module\module.psm1"


#if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`" `"$args`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

function B ($optionalParam=$null){#somecode}
```

Q1. I'd like to know if "override" mecanism (or what I want to achieve) is possible or provided in powershell script.

Q2. And why how I'm proceeding is working in a case and not the other, i.e admin mode vs not admin.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I don't think you are on the right track as you "mother" depends on the child which puts everything upside down. I guess that the first example works *not because your in "Admin mode"* but because you loading a new PowerShell session. More likely you want to do something like a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)): `function A ($optionnalParam, [ScriptBlock]$B){ &$B }`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. You are 100% right ! You gave me the right path to achieve what I want. You seem to know powershell very well, would you suggest me any advanced and detailed documentation ? I'm looking for a discord small but reactive group to fast share about programming, do you use and would you be up to adding me to discord by any chance ? Thanks